# How to Whitelist an IP Address Using Mod_Security

Tags: apache, magento, mod-security

I cannot access my magneto admin panel.I have added below code to .htaccess .syntax code is not working for me.please tell me how to disable the mod_security for my IP address.

**syntax code:**

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Addr ^208.xxx.xxx.103$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off
```

****Error : ****

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /manage on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you decide to do with **.htaccess** per folder:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Addr ^208\.xxx\.xxx\.103$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off
```

If you decide to do with **mod_security.conf** per server:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^208\.xxx\.xxx\.103$" phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off
```

Comment: I used @ipMatch instead of a regex. And I read ModSecurity cannot be configured anymore in an .htaccess file: https://sourceforge.net/p/mod-security/mailman/message/9858661/

Answer (score 6):

It is important to know which phase you need to apply your rule. In my case, and maybe the most of the cases, you should user this command:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 66.249.0.0/16" "id:26091975,phase:2,pass,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

You may notice that I am allowing Googlebot to access using a ip-block

You may read this official info to get more confident
https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#ipMatch

I my particular case, I am using this command in:
/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf

[image: You can see working the rule I've just set]